# Finding an orthogonal basis of the subspace spanned by given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let W be the subspace spanned by the given vectors. Find a basis for $W^\perp$.
>   $$v_1=(2,1,-2) ;v_2=(4,0,1)$$

Well I did the following to find the basis.

> $$(x,y,z)*(2,1,-2)=0$$ $$(x,y,z)*(4,0,1)=0$$

If you simplify this in to a Linear equation

> $$2x + y - 2z = 0$$ $$4x + z = 0$$

Now bu placing this in a vector and performing row echelon I get

$$ w = 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &\ 0 &\ 1/4 &0\\ 
0&\ 1 &\ -5/2 &0
\end{array} \right]$$

By solving this I get

> $$x=-1/4 t$$
>   $$y=5/2 t$$
>   $$z=t$$

By this I get the basis to be.

> $$[-1/4, 5/2 ,1]$$

I don't see that the answer is correct because you get the vector space in the someway. Please tell me if I used the correct method.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

First, multiply by four the vector you got at the end. This will make things way simpler to check that it indeed is orthogonal to both given generators of $\,W\,$ .

Second, you know $\,\dim W=2\;$ and thus we know that it **must** be that $\,\dim W^\perp=1\;$, which makes the linear span of the vector you got the very subspace $\,W^\perp\,$ itself.

Thus, you did all correctly but you didn't know that and, hopefully, now you do!

Answer (score 1):

Since you work in $\mathbb R^3$ so simply take $v_3=v_1\wedge v_2=(1,-10,-4)$.

Comment: Where would you get v3?

Comment: $v_3$ is the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$.